# Can I travel from Serbia to Budapest with just my Czech Republic ID?

Tags: borders, czech-republic, identity-cards, serbia

Does the train from Beograde to Budapest stop at the border or does the passport controller come into the train?

Comment: The title and body of your question are asking two totally different things.

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question several times. Thank you.